# Identify Crash log in iOS

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

We have used several 3rd party crash logs in past like crittercism, Flurry, crashlytics etc. There're some crash logs in which we are not able to get exact crash point. So, do we have any tool available which provides exact crash point ?

OR which is best 3rd party crash log tools in iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of crash, stack traces may not contain any of your apps code, which is perfectly fine.

Especially when dealing with memory issues, the crash will happen somewhere completely different than where the bug in your application is. You will have to check for the Exception Type information in the crash log and then go from there.

The following documents can help you understand crash reports better:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

You should also use the tools Xcode provides to make sure there are no easy to detect bugs by using the Instruments Leaks tool, use the Analyze build feature in Xcode, or the Address Sanitizer check in Xcode 7.